# get an index value of a Pandas dataframe in dependency of another column's max() value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe. The index of the dataframe is a datetime column namely "time".
How is it possible to call a special value of the datetime index column in dependency of another columns max() value?

The dataframe example:

```
                      Temperature   Humidity        Height
 time                                                                       
 2022-03-17 12:52:27   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 2022-03-17 12:52:28   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 2022-03-17 12:52:29   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 2022-03-17 12:52:30   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 2022-03-17 12:52:31   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 ...                          ...        ...           ...  
 2022-03-17 14:28:07   220.382478   0.929040  26529.819649  
 2022-03-17 14:28:08   220.355416   0.933099  26534.843300  
 2022-03-17 14:28:09   220.327658   0.937137  26539.820942   
 2022-03-17 14:28:10   220.300062   0.941082  26544.776129   
 2022-03-17 14:28:11   220.272778   0.944972  26549.735739 
 ...                          ...        ...           ...  
 2022-03-17 16:02:17   280.278408  73.551713    789.406738  
 2022-03-17 16:02:18   280.278408  73.551713    789.406738  
 2022-03-17 16:02:19   280.278408  73.551713    789.406738   
 2022-03-17 16:02:20   280.278408  73.551713    789.406738   
 2022-03-17 16:02:11   280.278408  73.551713    789.406738
```

What I am looking for is something like:

```
event = df.index[(df.Height.max())]
print(event)
2022-03-17 14:28:11
```

The code line above leads to an IndexError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-42b68005c09f> in <module>
---> 34 print(df.index[(df.Height.max())])  

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   5037             # GH#44051 exclude bool, which would return a 2d ndarray
   5038             key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key, warn_float=True)
-> 5039             return getitem(key)
   5040 
   5041         if isinstance(key, slice):

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    339         # (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44624)
    340         result = cast(
--> 341             "Union[DatetimeLikeArrayT, DTScalarOrNaT]", super().__getitem__(key)
    342         )
    343         if lib.is_scalar(result):

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\_mixins.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    279         key = extract_array(key, extract_numpy=True)  # type: ignore[assignment]
    280         key = check_array_indexer(self, key)
--> 281         result = self._ndarray[key]
    282         if lib.is_scalar(result):
    283             return self._box_func(result)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

```
event = df.Height.idxmax()
print(event)
2022-03-17 14:28:11
```